How can I resolve memory issues occurring with scipy's BDF integrator
I am attempting to propagate a physical system along a time-like axis. The solution is expected to be stiff, so I have opted to try scipy's solve_ivp function. The simulation works for three time steps and then crashes (memory profile attached). The simplified executable:
from psi4Integrals import get_integrals
from scipy import integrate as ode
import numpy as np
import ACSEtools as acse
import gc

def derivative(t, tensor):
    global consts4D, consts2D, dim, small_dim, scalar

    # Reshsape tpdm and contract to opdm
    tensor = np.reshape(tensor, (dim, dim, dim, dim))
    matrix = acse.contract_D2_to_D1(tensor, small_dim, dim)
    temp = acse.NY(tensor, matrix, dim, small_dim)

    # Calculate antihermitian operator S
    s1 = acse.com1(tensor,matrix,consts4D,consts2D)
    s2 = acse.com2(temp, tensor, matrix, consts4D, consts2D)

    # Caclculate time derivative
    dtensor = acse.com2(temp, tensor, matrix, s2, s1)

    # Calculate and store energy
    E = acse.energy_eval(tensor, dim, small_dim, consts4D, consts2D, scalar)
    f = open("Be:6-31G(d).csv", 'a')
    f.write(str(t) + ',' + str(E) + '\n')
    f.close
    print(t)

    del temp, tensor, matrix, s1, s2, E, f, t
    gc.collect()
    return dtensor.ravel()


def main():
    global consts4D, consts2D, dim, small_dim, scalar

    # Initialize physical constants
    small_dim, a, dim, consts2D, consts4D, scalar, b = get_integrals()

    # Initialize a matrix
    matrix = np.zeros((dim, dim), dtype = np.float64)
    for i in range(0, small_dim):
        matrix[i, i] = 1.0

    # Find the antisymetric tensor product of the matrix
    tensor = np.einsum('ik,jl-> ijkl', matrix, matrix) - np.einsum('il,jk->ijkl', matrix, matrix)

    # Integrate
    sol = ode.BDF(derivative, y0 = tensor.ravel(), t0 = 0, t_bound = 1, vectorized = False, max_step = 1e-4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Relevant functions from other files:
def contract_D2_to_D1(D2, nsocc, nmo):
    """
    contract the 2RDM to the 1RDM

    :param D2: the 2RDM
    :param nsocc: the number of occupied spin orbitals
    :param nmo: the number of molecular spin orbitals

    :return D1: the 1RDM
    """

    D1 = np.zeros([nmo, nmo])

    # build D1 from D2
    for i in range (0, nmo):
        for j in range (0, nmo):
            dum = 0.0
            for k in range (0, nmo):
                dum += D2[i, k, j, k]
            D1[i, j] = 1.0 / (nsocc - 1.0) * dum
    return D1

def NY(D2, D1, nmo, nsocc):
    V = 2.0 * D2 - tt.TwoTwoWedge(D1, D1)
    product = np.einsum('ijal, kamn -> ijklmna', V, V)
    del V
    perms = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6), (0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6), (1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6), (1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6)]
    dum = np.zeros((nmo, nmo, nmo, nmo, nmo, nmo, nmo))
    for perm in perms:
        dum += np.transpose(product, perm)

    del product, perms
    coeff = 1.0/6.0
    # Turn this into a function
    ind = np.where(np.indices(dum.shape)[-1] >= nsocc)
    dum[ind] *= -1
    del ind
    dum = np.sum(dum, axis = -1)


    dum *= coeff
    del coeff
    gc.collect()
    return dum

def com1(A2, A1, B2, B1):
    # com1 = +1.00 h(k,p) A1(i,p)  // flops: o0v2 = o0v3 | mem: o0v2 = o0v2
    com1 = einsum('kp,ip->ik', B1, A1)

    # com1 += -1.00 h(p,i) A1(p,k)  // flops: o0v2 += o0v3 | mem: o0v2 += o0v2
    com1 -= einsum('pi,pk->ik', B1, A1)

    # com1 += +0.50 g(k,p,r,q) A2(i,p,r,q)  // flops: o0v2 += o0v5 | mem: o0v2 += o0v2
    com1 += 0.50 * einsum('kprq,iprq->ik', B2, A2)

    # com1 += +0.50 g(p,q,i,r) A2(p,q,r,k)  // flops: o0v2 += o0v5 | mem: o0v2 += o0v2
    com1 += 0.50 * einsum('pqir,pqrk->ik', B2, A2)

    return com1

def com2(A3, A2, A1, B2, B1):
    tmps_ = {}

    # com2 = +0.50 g(p,q,i,j) A2(p,q,l,k)  // flops: o0v4 = o0v6 | mem: o0v4 = o0v4
    com2 = 0.50 * einsum('pqij,pqlk->ijlk', B2, A2)

    # com2 += -0.50 g(l,k,q,p) A2(i,j,q,p)  // flops: o0v4 += o0v6 | mem: o0v4 += o0v4
    com2 -= 0.50 * einsum('lkqp,ijqp->ijlk', B2, A2)

    # tmps_[1_vvvv](k,l,j,i) = 0.50 A3(i,j,p,r,q,l) * g[vvvv](k,p,r,q) // flops: o0v4 = o0v7 | mem: o0v4 = o0v4
    tmps_["1_vvvv"] = 0.50 * einsum('ijprql,kprq->klji', A3, B2)

    # com2 += +0.50 P(k,l) g(l,p,r,q) A3(i,j,p,r,q,k)  // flops: o0v4 += o0v4 | mem: o0v4 += o0v4
    com2 += einsum('lkji->ijlk', tmps_["1_vvvv"])
    com2 -= einsum('klji->ijlk', tmps_["1_vvvv"])
    del tmps_["1_vvvv"]

    # tmps_[2_vvvv](j,k,l,i) = 0.50 A3(i,p,q,r,l,k) * g[vvvv](p,q,j,r) // flops: o0v4 = o0v7 | mem: o0v4 = o0v4
    tmps_["2_vvvv"] = 0.50 * einsum('ipqrlk,pqjr->jkli', A3, B2)

    # com2 += -0.50 P(i,j) g(p,q,i,r) A3(j,p,q,r,l,k)  // flops: o0v4 += o0v4 | mem: o0v4 += o0v4
    com2 -= einsum('iklj->ijlk', tmps_["2_vvvv"])
    com2 += einsum('jkli->ijlk', tmps_["2_vvvv"])
    del tmps_["2_vvvv"]

    # tmps_[3_vvvv](l,k,j,i) = 1.00 A2(i,j,p,k) * h[vv](l,p) // flops: o0v4 = o0v5 | mem: o0v4 = o0v4
    tmps_["3_vvvv"] = einsum('ijpk,lp->lkji', A2, B1)

    # com2 += -1.00 P(k,l) h(l,p) A2(i,j,p,k)  // flops: o0v4 += o0v4 | mem: o0v4 += o0v4
    com2 -= einsum('lkji->ijlk', tmps_["3_vvvv"])
    com2 += einsum('klji->ijlk', tmps_["3_vvvv"])
    del tmps_["3_vvvv"]

    # tmps_[4_vvvv](j,k,l,i) = 1.00 A2(i,p,l,k) * h[vv](p,j) // flops: o0v4 = o0v5 | mem: o0v4 = o0v4
    tmps_["4_vvvv"] = einsum('iplk,pj->jkli', A2, B1)

    # com2 += -1.00 P(i,j) h(p,i) A2(j,p,l,k)  // flops: o0v4 += o0v4 | mem: o0v4 += o0v4
    com2 -= einsum('iklj->ijlk', tmps_["4_vvvv"])
    com2 += einsum('jkli->ijlk', tmps_["4_vvvv"])
    del tmps_["4_vvvv"]

    return com2

def get_integrals():
    """

    get one- and two-electron integrals from psi4

    :return nsocc: number of occupied orbitals
    :return nsvirt: number of virtual orbitals
    :return h: the core hamiltonian matrix (spin-orbital basis)
    :return gtei: antisymmetrized two-electron integrals (spin-orbital basis)

    """

    psi4.core.be_quiet()

    # Set molecules
    mol = psi4.geometry("""

    Be 

    symmetry = c1
    """)

    # set options
    psi4.set_options({
                      'basis': '6-31G',
                      'scf_type': 'pk',
                      'e_convergence': 1e-8,
                      'd_convergence': 1e-8})

    # compute the Hartree-Fock energy and wave function
    scf_e, wfn = psi4.energy('SCF', return_wfn=True)
    E_nuc = mol.nuclear_repulsion_energy()

    # number of doubly occupied orbitals
    no   = wfn.nalpha()
    # total number of orbitals
    nmo     = wfn.nmo()
    # number of virtual orbitals
    nv   = nmo - no

    # orbital energies
    epsilon     = np.asarray(wfn.epsilon_a())

    # molecular orbitals (spatial):
    C = wfn.Ca()

    # use Psi4's MintsHelper to generate integrals
    mints = psi4.core.MintsHelper(wfn.basisset())

    # build the one-electron integrals
    H = np.asarray(mints.ao_kinetic()) + np.asarray(mints.ao_potential())
    H = np.einsum('uj,vi,uv', C, C, H)

    # unpack one-electron integrals in spin-orbital basis
    sH   = spatial_to_spin_orbital_oei(H,nmo,no)

    # build the two-electron integrals:
    tei = np.asarray(mints.mo_eri(C, C, C, C))

    # unpack two-electron integrals in spin-orbital basis
    stei = spatial_to_spin_orbital_tei(tei,nmo,no)

    # antisymmetrize g(ijkl) = <ij|kl> - <ij|lk> = (ik|jl) - (il|jk)
    gtei = np.einsum('ikjl->ijkl', stei) - np.einsum('iljk->ijkl', stei)

    # occupied, virtual slices
    n = np.newaxis
    o = slice(None, 2 * no)
    v = slice(2 * no, None)

    nsvirt = 2 * nv
    nsocc = 2 * no
    nmo = nsocc + nsvirt
    fci_e = psi4.energy("fci")
    print(scf_e)
    print("\n")
    print(fci_e)
    del mol, scf_e, no, epsilon, C, mints, H, stei, n, o, v
    return nsocc, nsvirt, nmo, sH, gtei, E_nuc, fci_e


Memory profiling resulted in this graph:Time vs. Memory Allocation
Replacing the get_integrals() function with a random numbers generated by numpy seems to have alleviated the issue, but I don't see how replacing an array of floats with another array of floats would reduce memory consumption.
I understand the BDF algorithm stores information on previous steps, and I have attempted to adjust the saved steps to avoid excessive memory usage to no avail. Regardless, 200 GB seems excessive for the system I am trying to integrate (dim = 9) any tips or help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!
Edit:
Below is the line by line trace of 'NY':

for 'contract_D2_to_D1':


How many orbitals are there?  Taking any number to the ninth power produces big numbers.  If nmo were 10, then dum by itself would be 4GB.

@TimRoberts The smallest set the program crashes has 9 orbitals. I am only propagating the two particle matrix, and reconstructing the three particle matrix at each step. If I understand how scipy works, only arrays of the size of the two particle density matrix are stored, so I don't see how calculations that are repeated every step spontaneously cause a crash.

Can you obtain a line-by-line trace from memory_profiler of those two functions?

@NickODell Sorry for the delay, I'm assuming you mean the 'NY' and 'contract_D2_to_D1', which I have added to the post.

Can you try reducing memory usage by replacing ind = np.where(np.indices(dum.shape)[-1] >= nsocc); dum[ind] *= -1 with dum[..., nsocc:] *= -1 ? Should be able to use slicing to accomplish what you're doing here, and it would allocate a lot less memory. (Note: assumes that nsocc is an int.)

@NickODell This seems to have lowered the memory use for each iteration, but the spike in allocation from the original time profile is still present.

Do you have a traceback of the MemoryError? Or does it just crash?

@NickODell The program crashes

Can you hit Ctrl-C at the point where it starts allocating lots and lots of memory, and see what line it's at?

@NickODell The remaining processes after signal interruption seem to be numpy routines so the lines and sources are unknown.

Does it give you a traceback? That would tell you where the call to numpy is coming from.
